# Running LocalSTS without starting Visual Studio as Administrator

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wif

What steps are needed to allow Visual Studio to start the LocalSTS without running as an Administrator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a command line (that's running as administrator)

```
Netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:15306/wsFederationSTS/ user={user name}
Netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:15306/wsTrustSTS/ user={user name}
```

Change the port number to reflect the port shown in the LocalSTS error dialog (example bellow, in my case it was 15306) and specify the user that's running Visual Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not designed to run as a standard user. unfortunately.